# $|\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{N}|$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Hello all, if you could give some critique on my proof I would be grateful.

Show that $|\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{N}|$ for,

$$\displaystyle f(n) = \begin{cases} 2|n|+1, \text{if} & n\leq0 \\ 2n, \text{if} & n>0\end{cases}$$

By the definition of cardinality (def. 2.10b) we note that if a function is bijective, cardinality of the sets equal to one another. So, we want to show that $f(n)$ is bijective. To prove that $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ injective, we must show $\forall n_1,n_2\in \mathbb{Z}$, if $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$ then $n_1=n_2$ for both conditions of $f(n)$, so,

$f(n)=2|n|+1 $, if $ n\leq 0$
$2|n_1|+1 = 2|n_2|+1$
$2|n_1|=2|n_2|$
$|n_1|=|n_2|$

and

$f(n)=2n$, if $n>0$
$2n_1=2n_2$
$n_1=n_2$

Thus we see that $f(n)$ is clearly injective. To prove $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is surjective, meaning $\exists n\in \mathbb{Z},\forall r\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $f(n)=r$, again for both conditions,

$f(n)=2|n|+1 $, if $ n\leq 0$ 
$r=2|n|+1$
$r-1=2|n|$ 
$|n|=\frac{r-1}{2}$

and

$f(n)=2n$, if $n>0$
$r=2n$
$n=\frac{r}{2}$

Thus we see that for both conditions $f(n)=r$, and function $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is surjective. Hence, we prove $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is bijective as it is injective and surjective. Therefore, by definition of cardinality, we say that cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: All countable infinite sets have the same cardinality. For example , the rational numbers have the same cardinality as the natural numbers. This is still true for the numbers algebraic over the rationals.

Comment: I just want to say that I like the effort you have put into making this post accessible with the formatting and math and all. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to latex and it seems I copied wrong question, edited.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the edit ... that makes more sense! I wondered what was going on :)

Comment: Again, apologies, I edited the question, I am very new to latex.

Comment: @Peter True, but that is a statement which needs to be proven. Alternatively, depending on what definitions your working with, it needs to be proven that $\Bbb Z$ is countably infinite. That is what this problem is about, and just saying something along the lines of "They're both countably infinite" probably isn't good enough.

Comment: @Peter That's true but it is an advanced result and can't just be claimed because we say so.  We do have to prove it.  We can suggest that the OP simply not bother to do his/her prove and prove that all infinite countable sets have the same cardinality instead.  That may be more efficient but I think that would not be a good idea when it comes to teaching.  I think the OP will learn a *lot* by attempting a proof of this type.  And I think the OP *did* do a very good job.

Comment: A minor oversight.  If $f(n_1) = f(n_2)$ it possible (hypothetically) that $n_1\le 0$ is even and $n_2 > 0$ (or vice versa)  Is you must prove that if $2|n_1| + 1 = 2|n_2|$ is impossible. ... Actually $|n_1| = |n_2| \not \implies n_1 = n_2$.  $|n_1| = |n_2|\implies n_1 = \pm n_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very very close.

But:

You say "Now, suppose f(n) is injective, meaning ∀n1,n2∈Z, if f(n1)=f(n2) then n1=n2 for both conditions of f(n), so,..."

This is what you want to *prove*. You are not "supposing" it.  ANd the "so...." does not follow as a result.  What follows is your attempt to prove it.

ANd then

$f(n) = 2|n| + 1$ if $n \le 0$

$2|n_1| + 1 = 2|n_2| + 1$.  But you do not know if $n_1, n_2$ are positive or negative.  You must conisder *all* options that $f(n_1) = f(n_2)$ even if they are different signs.

And then you get:

$|n_1| = |n_2|$ therefore

$n_1 = n_2$.  That is not true.  It is possible that $n_1 = -n_2$.

You might need to do cases:

$f(n_1) = f(n_2)$

Case 1: $n_1 \le0; n_2\le 0$.

$2|n_1|+1 = 2|n_2| + 1$

$|n_1| = |n_2|$ but as $n_1 \le 0$ and $|n_2 \le 0$

$-n_1 = - n_2$ and $n_1 = n_2$.

Case 2: $n_1 > 0; n_2>0$.

Then $2|n_1| = 2|n_2|$

$|n_1| = |n_2|$ but as both are positive

$n_1 = n_2$.

Case 3: $n_1 \le 0$ and $n_2 > 0$

Then $2|n_1| + 1= 2|n_2|$.

This is an odd number equaling an even number.  This is impossible.

Case 4: $n_1 > 0; n_2 \le 0$

This is no different essentially than case 3.

...

Notice it might be easier if you had done

$f(n) = -2n + 1$ if $ n \le 0$ and $f(n) = 2n$ if $n > 0$.

Then we could say $f(n_1) = f(n_2) $ means either

1) $-2n_1 + 1 = -2n_2 + 1$

2) $2n_1 = 2n_2$

3) $-2n_1 + 1 = 2n_2$

4) $2n_1 = -2n_2 + 1$.

1) and 2) both reveal $n_1 = n_2$.

3) $n_2 = -n_1 + \frac 12$.  Which is impossible as the RHS is not an integer.

4) $n_1 = -n_2 + \frac 12$.  Ditto.

.... oh.... Your surjectivity is kind of a mess.

To prove surjectivity you choose and arbitrary $r \in \mathbb N$ and prove there must be an $n \in \mathbb Z$ so that $f(n) = r$.  You have to *start* with the $r$ and prove there is an $n$ that goes to it.  You can't start with the $n$.  You get $n = |\frac {r-1}2|$.  Well, so?  How do you know that that is even an integer.  It isn't if $r$ is even.  How do you know $r$ is odd?

So suppose $r \in \mathbb N$.  Either $r$ is even.  Or $r$ is odd$.

If $r$ is even let $n = \frac r2$.  And $n > 0$ we know $n =\frac r2 > 0$.

So $f(n) = 2|n| = 2|\frac r2| = |r| = r$.

If $r$ is odd, let $n = -\frac {r-1} 2$.  So $r \ge 1$ then $n = -\frac {r-1}2 \le 0$.

So $f(n) = 2|n| + 1= 2|-\frac {r-1}2| + 1 = 2*\frac {r-1}2 + 1 = (r-1) + 1 = r$.

So for any $r \in \mathbb N$ there will be an $n\in Z$ so that $f(n) = r$.

Again as youare defining $f$ in terms of whether $n$ is positive or non-positive, you don't/shouldn't define $f$ in terms of absolute values.

If $f(n) = 2|n| + 1$ then we *know* $n \le 0$ so just say $f(n) = -2n + 1$.

And if $f(n) = 2|n|$ when we *know* $n > 0$ so just say $f(n) = 2n$.

Also as Yves Daoust suggest:

consider defining $g: \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ as $g(n) = \frac n2$ if $n$ is even, and $g(n) = -\frac {n-1}2$ if $n$ is odd.

You'll find this direction is a bit easier and more natural (although your direction is also correct.)

If $n$ if even then $g(n) = \frac n2 > 0$.  If $n$ is odd then $g(n) = -\frac {n-1} 2 \le 0$.

So if $g(n) = g(m) > 0$ then $m,n$ are both even and $\frac m2 = \frac n2$ so $m = n$.

And if $g(n) = g(m) \le 0$ then $m,n$ are both odd and $-\frac {m-1}2=-\frac {n-1}2$ so $m = n$.

So $g$ is injective.

And for any $r \in \mathbb Z; r >0$ then $n = 2r \in \mathbb N$ and $g(n) = \frac {2r}2 = r$.

And for any $r \in \mathbb Z; r \le 0$ then $n = -2r + 1 \in \mathbb N$ and $g(n)=- \frac {(-2r + 1)-1}2= r$.

So $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this!

Answer (score 2):

- Before you show that something is a bijection, first write down what is the function being discussed.
- We don't suppose something is an injective/ surjective if we want to prove that they are injective or surjective.
- From $|n|=\frac{r-1}2$, we do not have $n = |\frac{r-1}2|$.
- While $f$ is indeed injective, it is not clear to me how is it clear to you that it is injective. In fact your working of injective and surjective are exactly the same. To prove injective, assume $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$ and deduce that $n_1=n_2$.
- For the proof of surjection, hightlight that the preimage indeed comes from $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks, inexperience with latex. I edited.

Comment: you might like to rule out $f(n_1) = f(n_2)$ where $n_1 \le 0$ and $n_2 >0$ too.

Answer (score 2):

Using common sense:

- send even naturals to positives,
- send odd naturals to negatives.

This is clearly reversible and establishes a bijection. Some care is required in the vicinity of $0$, but if necessary you can adjust by translation.